# What is a word for something that hurts and helps all at once?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe something that is both good for you and hurts you at the same time?
Sample sentence: "

Comment: You may be looking for **covfefe**.

Comment: Looks like the sample sentence got covfefefied.

Comment: "Covfefe is a ***bitter pill to swallow***."

Comment: In physical therapy one can call this "good pain* or "helpful pain."

Comment: Please give us a context and a sample sentence.

Comment: Productive pain.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest thing to what you're looking for is the phrase "[double-edged sword](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-edged%20sword)."

> Something that has or can have both favorable and unfavorable consequences.

But there are words that could be used as well in certain situations. One is "[pyrrhic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pyrrhic)."

> Achieved at excessive cost (a Pyrrhic victory); also :  costly to the
>   point of negating or outweighing expected benefits.

Another could be "[bittersweet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet)."

> Being at once bitter and sweet; especially :  pleasant but including
>   or marked by elements of suffering or regret

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Evan's good suggestions, you might also consider a "[bitter pill to swallow](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+bitter+pill)": *An unwanted or unpleasant situation that someone is forced to accept.*

> When Brett's parents stopped giving him money to pay his bills and told him to get a job, it was a *bitter pill for him to swallow*.
>
> Getting a poor performance review was a *bitter pill*, but it made me a better worker.

Pills might be necessary or helpful, but still taste bad going down.

Comment: Bitter pill is **just right.**

Answer (score 0):

Purgative and cathartic also have similar connotations. They mean something that's purifying/cleansing and, at the same time, hurting/punishing a bit.

E.g. *"infernal punishments are purgatory and medicinal"*

[Meaning of Purgative](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=purgatory&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIN726IN728&oq=purgat&aqs=chrome.0.0j5j69i57j0.3951j0j4&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)